# gpg --decrypt not asking for password and just decrypting, why?

Tags: gnupg

So I encrypt a file using symmetric AES encryption with `gnupg 2.2.9`:

`gpg -a --symmetric myfile # This produces myfile.asc as its output`

I am prompted for a password and enter it. The `-a` option produces an ASCII armored file - a file that contains only printable characters instead of a binary encrypted file. This type of file can be easily emailed as text and placed in the body of an email, rather than as an attachment.

Now to decrypt it, I use:

```
gpg --decrypt myfile.asc # This should decrypt myfile.asc to STDOUT after asking
                         # me for the password used during encryption
```

gpg tells me (via output to STDERR) that the file was encrypted with AES and was encrypted with 1 passphrase. OK, that makes sense.

However, gpg then proceeds to just decrypt the file to STDOUT without ever prompting me for a password, as if it was not password protected during encryption or not encrypted at all.

Why is this?

Comment: Please include an example payload (e.g: the contents of `myfile.asc`)

Comment: Note: I don't see this behaviour...

Comment: Try to logout then re-login and try to decrypt again.

Answer (score 1):

One answer is provided here: [GnuPG decryption not asking for passphrase](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103034/gnupg-decryption-not-asking-for-passphrase).

However, the following will work as well:

```
gnupg --pinentry-mode loopback --decrypt ...
```